# Coconut yoghurt too thick

Tags: fermentation, yogurt, thickness, xanthan

I've been trying to make a creamy coconut yoghurt in an incubator. Ingredients:

- Water
- Coconut milk powder
- Small amount of store-bought coconut yoghurt

The first time it came out too thin. The next time I used: less water, 1/4-1/2 teaspoon of xanthan gum (for about 800ml of yoghurt), and increased the incubation time. The result was far too thick, like hard-set jelly. Later some watery stuff separated from it (whey, I suppose). It was fine as a dessert but completely lacked the texture I was after.

I want to try again, but I'd like to know what I did wrong last time. Was it most likely to be too much fat, the gum, or the longer incubation time?

Comment: As you are using the yogurt as starter, did you check whether it has living bacteria in it? Also, the count simply might be to little. Do you have any info on that? You might try high-dose probiotic capsules with 50 Billion bacteria or so